# Force DNS resolution to use TCP

Tags: macos, dns, tcp, udp

My Comcast internet connection has been giving problems in DNS resolution, and I am guessing the reason is a probably broken or limited UDP. I am currently working around it by tunneling over TCP through a VPN, but to get the IP address of the server hosting the VPN I had to do a `dig @8.8.8.8 +tcp <hostname>`.

I am wondering if there is a configuration to enforce DNS resolutions over TCP instead of UDP?

Answer (score 1):

The glibc has a `use-vc` option to force TCP. The OpenBSD libc has a `tcp` option. However the FreeBDS, DragonFlyBSD and NetBSD do not have this option AFAIK. Mas OS/X / Darwin libresolv [does not seem to have a corresponding option](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libresolv/libresolv-57/res_init.c) (same as FreeBSD, NetBSD, DragonFlyBSD).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/henices/Tcp-DNS-proxy (not tested)

Something like that should work?